# How to generate Retrofit client library from wp rest api using swagger

Tags: android, wordpress, swagger, retrofit2, wp-api

I am creating android client for my WordPress website . Is there a way to generate retrofit 2 client library from wp rest client using swagger or is there any other tool to generate the same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion with wp-api team they are not providing any HTTP client library for android and also they are not planning to provide the same .

Please follow below link for the issue created in wp-api

https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2473

Answer (score 6):

Citing from [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/465), yes it is part of the existing codegen module of swagger:

> The latest Java API client supports different HTTP client including
>   Retrofit. To use Retrofit, please create a config.json file as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> {
>   "library": "retrofit"
> }
> ```
>
> and pass config.json via -c in the command line
>
> You can run java -jar
>   modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar config-help
>   -l java for more information on customizing the Java API client.

Comment: I know that swagger support retrofit but where Do I get API specification from or do I need to write by myself . Or is there any other way

Comment: You need to provide the API specification (OpenAPI/Swagger) in order to generate the Retrofit2 client.

Comment: @wing328 That is what i don't want to do. Wp-api provide client lib for javascript , angularjs and for some other languages too. I just want to is there any already written client side library .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a swagger 2.0 you better try [Swagger Gradle Codegen](https://github.com/Yelp/swagger-gradle-codegen), 
Generates Kotlin code and Retrofit interfaces, with RxJava2 for async calls, Moshi for serialization and ThreeTenABP for Data management